# Linq Left Join returns repeated same rows for all set

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

my linq returns all repeated same rows for all set

run SQL in DB :

```
select top 20 * from t1
left join t2
on t1.sid= t2.sid
 and t1.pid=t2.pid
where(t2.sid is null and t1.pid='r')
```

i can get 20 different rows of result.

then i write Linq:

```
    Entities dbconn = new Entities();
    List<t1> myResult = (
        from t1Data in dbconn.t1
        join t2Data in dbconn.t2
        on new     { sid = (int)t1.sid,    pid= t1.pid}
        equals new { sid= (int)t2.sid, pid= t2.pid}
        into joinSet
        from joinUnit in joinSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (joinUnit == null) && (t1.pid== "r")
        select t1Data 
        ).Take(20).ToList();
```

all rows of result are the some row.

Answer (score 1):

`select t1Data` is wrong as `t1Data` is from the *original* dataset.

Instead, select the joined result: `select joinSet`.